# How to change the color of default underline in textviews for Android App Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am creating a demo app in Android Studio with the following design, but the problem is that when I run the app in my mobile phone, the first underline is green, while the other one looks black. How can I change the color of this automatically generated underlines, so that they both have same color.

I know, I can create a view to add lines, but I like the placement of these lines and was thinking if there is a way to change their color rather than adding new lines through views.

[image: Screenshot: Android Studio]

The image I see in my phone:

[image: Screenshot: Phone]

As you can see the first line becomes green.

Code for first edittext:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:text="@string/today_text"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:inputType="text" />
```

Code for second edittext:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
    android:text="@string/tomorrow_text"
    android:inputType="text" />
```

Comment: It's default in lollipop, to do that in lower versions, you need 3rd party library and there are a lot of them.

Comment: I believe the green is used when the `EditText` is 'selected', and black when it is not. I think you should be using `Views` to create your lines rather than rely on the `EditText`, which is functioning correctly. You could set the first edittext to be unselected when the Activity starts so that they appear black until the user clicks on one...